# Should I create separate endpoint for public user and current user in rails api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, authorization, rails-api

I am building a rails api with a User model. My app will have a public profile for every user with basic attributes like username, avatar and bio. When you are logged in and you visit your profile, you see more information like which email newsletters you are subscribed to and private app data.

Which way should I implement it in my API:

1. Should I have one `GET user/:id` endpoint? If the user is not authorized (if they are not requesting their own data) then they receive the basic attributes back. If they are authorized (requesting their own user data) they will receive a response with the private app data.
   Is it bad to have an endpoint that returns different properties based on the authorization?
2. Should I have both a `GET /user/:id` endpoint which does not require authentication or authorization and only responds with basic info AND a `GET /profile` endpoint which responds only with the current users private app data?

Comment: I would choose option 1, as it is the same resource. It just responds with more attributes if the user is authorized. Let's see what others say.

Comment: Ya, you could pass in something like `{is_user: true}` or something to the seriallizer and conditionally use certain attributes. Or with something like BLueprinter, you could conditionally set the view based on if the current user is trying to see their own data or someone elses

Comment: thanks for the comments! I think I will go with 1. I am checking out Blueprinter as well.